# How to compute fast fourier transform aka fft using Ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fft

How can i compute fast Fourier transform of an audio signal using Ffmpeg. I know there is a library in Ffmpeg for doing that but no sure how.

Comment: put some code that u have tried

Comment: I have not tried any code , because i have no idea what to do with these C library files or how to use them in terminal like other Ffmpeg conversion commands. The the particular i am talking about is located here /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avfft.h . This is what i have found so far http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/fft-test_8c-source.html

Comment: Just because it has some code does not mean it has an external interface to that code. fft is an operation needed by several signal processing algorithms and that is why it will have that in there. if you want to do fft, use a fft library, ffmpeg is not for that